# Testing Stripe works with js: true, but it makes other components work incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, stripe-payments

Testing the stripe framework requires Javascript to be turned on, but when I send `js: true` in `it` method, the other components like `visit`, `fill_in` stop working in the way they were working before.

Here is my code:

```
def sign_up(subdomain)
    visit root_url(subdomain: false)
    visit new_account_path
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Ryan'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@test.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'Subdomain', with: subdomain
    click_button 'Create Account'
end
```

In the `sign_up` method, `visit new_account_path` was working before `js: true`, but now it doesn't.

I'm turning `js: true` in the following method:

```
it 'shows the user can upgrade his account with valid card number, expiration and CVC', js: true do
    fill_in "card_number", :with => "4242424242424242"
    fill_in "card_expiry_month", :with => "05"
    fill_in "card_expiry_year", :with => "2015"
    fill_in "card_cvc", :with => "123"
    click_button 'Upgrade Your Account'
    expect(page).to have_content "Update Your Payment Information"
end
```

I've been searching the solution for quite a long time, but so far unable to resolve this.

Comment: What exactly fails on that line? Do you get an error message or something else?

Comment: `Failure/Error: click_button 'Upgrade Your Account' Stripe::InvalidRequestError:` This is the error that I'm getting.

Comment: Ok, does stripe need to know a list of allowed urls? Is the url used during testing one of these allowed urls?

Comment: I don't know about what you are asking: But is there any way I can test `stripe` without doing `js: true`. Because when I do `js: true`, it causes problems: it doesn't let me `fill_in` some elements as I have described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you're getting an error from stripe's API: `Stripe::InvalidRequestError`.

According to their API (https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors):

> Invalid request errors arise when your request has invalid
>   parameters.

I would wager that there is something actually wrong with your request to Stripe rather than the Capybara (?) spec you wrote.

I've written a blog post about writing acceptance tests with RSpec and Capybara for Stripe. You can [view it here](https://pgord.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/how-i-wrote-acceptance-specs-for-stripe-jquery-payment-on-rails/)

Comment: @ArslanAli Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes. I'm! But does it have anything to do with Testing?

Comment: I've read several other stack overflows / github issues which detail that there are issues with turbolinks & stripe. Perhaps try disabling turbolinks and see if the issue persists with your test